# Keep only unique duplicated rows across multiple columns in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a dataFrame as follows:

```
>>> df
        brand  style  rating
    0  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
    1  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
    2  Nissin    cup     3.5
    3  Indomie  pack    15.0
    4  Indomie  pack     5.0
```

It is very easy to keep duplicates based on columns: **brand** and **style** using:

```
df = df[df.duplicated(['brand', 'style'], keep=False)]
```

The output:

```
>>> df = df[df.duplicated(['brand', 'style'], keep=False)]
>>> df
        brand  style  rating
    0  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
    1  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
    3  Indomie  pack    15.0
    4  Indomie  pack     5.0
```

But the rows that I only want to keep are row 3 and 4. Here's why:

The subset columns used for identifying duplicates are **brand** and **style**. Row 0 and row 1 are not "unique" duplicates because the **style** "cup" has occured once in row 2 as well. But row 3 and row 4 are unique duplicates because neither the **brand** "Indomie" nor the **style** "pack" has ever occured in any other rows.

Thus, how do I keep unique duplicates based on columns brand and style in order to get the expected output as below?

```
>>> df
        brand  style  rating
    3  Indomie  pack    15.0
    4  Indomie  pack     5.0
```

Comment: "Row 0 and row 1 are not "unique" duplicates because the style "cup" has occured once in row 2 as well. But row 3 and row 4 are unique duplicates because neither the brand "Indomie" nor the style "pack" has ever occured in any other rows" This sentence makes no sense to me, the brand "Indomie" occoures together with "cup" on line 2.

Comment: I miss-copied the data, should be fixed now

Answer (score 1):

```py
df = df[~df.duplicated()] # Add this line before
df[df.duplicated(['brand', 'style'], keep=False)]
    brand   style   rating
3   Indomie pack    15.0
4   Indomie pack    5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the number of unique values in one column based on values in another using groupby + `nunique()`:

```
>>> df.groupby('style')['brand'].nunique()
style
cup     2
pack    1
Name: brand, dtype: int64
>>> df.groupby('brand')['style'].nunique()
brand
Indomie    1
Nissin     1
Yum Yum    1
Name: style, dtype: int64
```

As always, you can get this with the original shape using `.transform('nunique')` instead. Now combine this with your first condition:

```
>>> df[df.duplicated(['style', 'brand'], keep=False)
... & df.groupby('style')['brand'].transform('nunique').eq(1)
... & df.groupby('brand')['style'].transform('nunique').eq(1)]
     brand style  rating
3  Indomie  pack    15.0
4  Indomie  pack     5.0
```